# What to do instead of the regex exp in awk

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, scripting

Right now I am using awk to search for a string I put into the regular expression, however I am trying to use a "defined variable" instead to make my code more reusable. My code I want to replace is:

```
awk '
    /lksdfjsalfjl/ { counter++}
    END{}
' file
```

While researching online I found out a variable cant be used inside of the /.../. Do you have any suggestions on an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `~` for regex matching:

```
awk -v x='lksdfjsalfjl'  '$0~x {counter++} END{print counter+0}' file
```

In more detail:

- `-v x='lksdfjsalfjl'`

  This defines a variable `x`
- `$0~x {counter++}`

  This increments the counter if the current line, `$0`, matches the regular expression in `x`.

You can, if your like, use a shell variable to set the awk variable:

```
a='lksdfjsalfjl'
awk -v x="$a"  '$0~x {counter++} END{print counter+0}' file
```

Comment: In awk, `$0` is the whole line.  While `$1` refers to the first field, `$2` the second, and so on, `$0` refers to the line as a whole.

Comment: @Alan FYI `/lksdfjsalfjl/` is just shorthand for `$0 ~ /lksdfjsalfjl/`. That shorthand ONLY works when the right side of the test is a static regexp, not when it's a dynamic regexp or a variable. The final print should be `print counter+0` to make sure you get a number printed even when nothing matches.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks.  Forcing counter to be numeric is a nice improvement.  Answer updated.

Comment: @EdMorton What does the +0 do?

Comment: Scalar variables in awk are all of the same type - "numeric string", and they are all initialized to the same somewhat confusing value of "zero or null". The first time you use a variable awk figures out if its actually a number or a string based on how it's used. If a variable is first used in a `print` statement then it's printed as a string with its initial string-associated value of `null` so in your case if counter is never incremented then the print will print a null string. By adding a `+0` to the print statement its telling awk that the value is a number and so it'll print zero instead